# Identify during Page.Load if Button click event is going to be handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I have ASPX web page which has a Button on it. Once user click this button, request is submitted to server and button click event handler is executed.

I have some logic that must reside on Page.Load, but this logic depends if request has been submitted by button click. Based on [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event handlers executes after Page Load.

**Question**: How in Page load I can find out what event handlers are going to be executed after Page Load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@akton's answer is probably what you SHOULD do, but in case you want to go off the reservation and determine what is causing a postback early on in the lifecycle, you can interrogate the postback data to determine what was clicked.  This will NOT give you what actual functions/handlers will be executed during event handling, however.

First, if something other than a `Button`/`ImageButton` caused the postback, the ID of the control will be in `__EVENTTARGET`.  If a `Button` caused the postback, there is something "cute" ASP.NET does: it ignores all other buttons so that only the clicked button shows up on the form.  An `ImageButton` is a little different, because it will send coordinates.  A utility function you can include:

```
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control postbackControlInstance = null;

    string postbackControlName = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (postbackControlName != null && postbackControlName != string.Empty)
    {
        postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(postbackControlName);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle the Button control postbacks
        for (int i = 0; i < page.Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(page.Request.Form.Keys[i]);
            if (postbackControlInstance is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                return postbackControlInstance;
            }
        }
    }
    // handle the ImageButton postbacks
    if (postbackControlInstance == null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < page.Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
            if ( (page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".x")) || (page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".y")))
            {
                postbackControlInstance = page.FindControl(page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Substring(0, page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Length-2) );
                return postbackControlInstance;
            }
        }
    }
    return postbackControlInstance;
}
```

All that being said, if you can refactor your control/page to delay execution, your code will be much cleaner/more robust if you use the paradigm suggested by @akton.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better solution to the problem. Do you want the code to only run when the page is first loaded and you are using postbacks? If so check the [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property. If the code does not need to run before other event handlers, move it to [OnPreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onprerender.aspx) because it fires after event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

These helped me a lot: I wanted to save values from my gridview, and it was reloading my gridview /overriding my new values, as i have IsPostBack inside my PageLoad.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["MYCLICKEDBUTTONID"] == null)

{ //Do not reload the gridview.

}

else { reload my gridview. }
```

SOURCE: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/312809-please-help-how-identify-button-clicked