# Button name on Content Page From Master Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my master page I have two buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-prev" Text="Prev" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-next" Text="Next" />
```

The user clicks on the and of course the page fires, great, except I want to do an action based on which button is pressed. I can go back and reference the Master Page as the first thing on the Content Page

```
Call btnNext_clickassessment(sender, e)
```

and

```
Protected Sub btnNext_clickassessment(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Me.Master.btnNext_Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

However this does not determine which button was actually pressed.

I have looked at `onclick` and  `If CType(sender, Button).ID = "btnNext_Click" Then` but nothave not found a solution yet (or one of those is an I've set it wrong!

Maybe even some javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which button caused postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229995/how-to-determine-which-button-caused-postback)

Comment: That's not got Master Pages..?

Comment: should work in the same way - you can check the sender or use a command and command argument, look at the comments in the accepted answer.

Comment: There does not appear to be an accepted answer. The one with three upvotes (not trying to be difficult want to look at the right one :-) )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10230165/2208 - this one

Comment: This fires the content page first still, I'll try the below answer and confirm :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also declare a public property on your master page and then handle the events on the content page as below

**MasterPage**

```
Public btnPrev As Button
Public btnNext As Button
```

**ContentPage**

```
'in page load
AddHandler Me.Master.btnPrev.Click, AddressOf Me.btnPrevNext_Click
AddHandler Me.Master.btnNext.Click, AddressOf Me.btnPrevNext_Click
```

and then your handler

```
Private Sub btnPrevNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Button clicks here
    dim btnName as string
    btnName = sender.ID
    ' do stuff with the button name
End Sub
```

Alternatively use two distinct handlers to simplify your code

**ContentPage**

```
'in page load
AddHandler Me.Master.btnPrev.Click, AddressOf Me.btnPrev_Click
AddHandler Me.Master.btnNext.Click, AddressOf Me.btnNext_Click
```

and then your handler

```
Private Sub btnPrev_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Previous Button click here
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Next Button click here
End Sub
```

Comment: So this would know which button had been pressed? i.e. if btnPrev OR btnNext had been pressed so only one is actioned?

Comment: you would need to check which button is pressed by checking the `btnName` or you could use two different handlers instead

Comment: Building test now, will confirm

Comment: I keep getting:   'btnPrevClick' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.  on the .aspx.vb content page